# How to use row_number function with two consecutive conditions

Tags: sql, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
    ID  IN_TIME SOURCE  LOGIN_NAME
    303954772   2019-01-01 06:37:33.900 R   ATMUSER
    303954772   2019-01-01 06:43:51.667 R   ATMUSER
    303954866   2019-01-01 07:34:47.790 R   ATMUSER
    303955362   2019-01-01 08:58:03.597 R   ATMUSER
    303955648   2019-01-01 10:26:23.533 R   ATMUSER
    303955700   2019-01-01 10:40:10.230 R   BAYI
    303955700   2019-01-02 10:40:10.933 R   BAYI
    303955700   2019-01-02 10:40:11.307 R   BAYI
    303954484   2019-01-01 11:06:07.440 R   ATMUSER
    303955854   2019-01-02 11:10:53.233 H   GUEST
    303933812   2019-01-02 11:11:27.247 R   ATMUSER
    303933812   2019-01-01 11:13:20.247 R   ATMUSER
```

What I want is to be seen like the following:

```
    ID  IN_TIME SOURCE  LOGIN_NAME  ROW_NUMBER
303954866   2019-01-01 06:37:33.900 R   ATMUSER 1
303955362   2019-01-01 06:43:51.667 R   ATMUSER 2
303955648   2019-01-01 07:34:47.790 R   ATMUSER 3
303955700   2019-01-01 08:58:03.597 R   ATMUSER 4
303955700   2019-01-01 10:26:23.533 R   ATMUSER 5
303954484   2019-01-01 11:06:07.440 R   ATMUSER 6
303954772   2019-01-01 11:11:27.247 R   ATMUSER 7
303955700   2019-01-01 10:40:10.230 R   BAYI    1
303954772   2019-01-02 11:13:20.247 R   ATMUSER 1
303955854   2019-01-02 10:40:10.933 R   BAYI    1
303933812   2019-01-02 10:40:11.307 R   BAYI    2
303933812   2019-01-02 11:10:53.233 H   GUEST   1
```

How can I do this by using row number function? Or something else that would only give the rows of 1 in row_number column could work too.

Answer (score 1):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands.  For this purpose, difference of row numbers seems sufficient:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by source, login_name, seqnum - seqnum2 order by in_time) as row_number
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by in_time) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by source, login_name order by in_time) as seqnum2
      from t
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just want to partition by the datepart of in_time and the login_name. Something like the below could work:

```
select a.*,
       row_number() over (partition by cast(in_time as date),login_name order by in_time) as rownum
from table a
order by cast(in_time as date),login_name,in_time
```

Hope this helps.